# Constructor not allowed a return type, but I have class closed with semicolon?

Tags: c++

first time posting. this is a homework question, but I have submitted it as is. This is for my own resolution because our professor takes forever to return work. I have a class created in a header file and I get the "constructor not allowed return type error', but as far as I can see, my class is closed with a semicolon.
The purpose of the header file is to grab a text file that is passed into fname.

Here is the code, which dies on line 13:

```
    #ifndef MYLIB
    #define MYLIB
    using namespace std;

    template <class T, int n>

    class ONE
    {
    private:
        T x[n];

    public:
        void ONE(string fname)
{
    //read data into array
    fstream file;
    file.open(fname, ios::in);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        file >> x[i];
    }
    file.close();
}
void Display()
{
    //display array x
    cout << "Original Characters: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void SortArray()
{
    //sort array x
    sort(x, x + n);
    cout << "Sorted characters: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << x[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

};
#endif
```

Comment: What does ending with a semicolon have to do with the error message?

Comment: The error message is complaining about `void ONE(string fname)`. You're not supposed to have a return type here.

Comment: You did not need all these functions to reproduce the problem. Make a [MCVE] when you write a question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `void` from your constructor definition and declaration. It should have no return type.

```
void ONE(string fname)
{
  ...
}
```

should be

```
ONE(string fname)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I responded to the others too, the professor gave us that void line. He is known for tpyos, thank you

Answer (score 0):

When declaring constructors, there should be no return type used at all. In your code, you currently have `void ONE(string fname)`, but the `void` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you, the professor gave us that bit of code, he is known for typos but I took it as is.

Answer (score 0):

It's what it says: a constructor should have no return type; remove it.

```
   void ONE(string fname)
// ^^^^
```

This has nothing to do with semicolons. Just read the error message.

Comment: thank you, on the assignment, the professor gave us the sample code of "void ONE(string fname)".

I was going off of his example, i should have known better, thank you.

Comment: @ajaxf1: Sounds like your professor shouldn't be teaching. Or, perhaps, it was a "trick question" with a deliberate error for you (read: us) to find!

Comment: nah, i have pointed out errors i caught before and he has apologized in the past. His class is 100% lecture with 0 examples given in a compiler

Comment: @ajaxf1: I'm sorry to hear that